# Consulta por movimentação

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela que registra etapas de uma movimentação.
Por exemplo:

> Data - Movimentacao - Produto
>  2018-30-10 - produzido - id1
>   2018-30-11 - embalado - id1
>  2018-30-12- despachado - id1
>   2018-30-10 - produzido - id2
>  2018-30-10 - produzido - id3
>   2018-30-11 - embalado - id3
>  2018-30-10 - produzido - id4

Gostaria de uma pesquisa que me retornasse os produtos que foram embalados e não despachados.
Mas só consegui fazer dentro de um laço na minha aplicação.
Consigo fazer isso com uma só consulta ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
SELECT    l.id
FROM      (SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'embalado'  ) l
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'despachado') r USING(id)
WHERE     r.id IS NULL
```

### Entendendo:

Esta tabela virtual (subquery) retorna apenas os embalados:

```
SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'embalado'
```

Esta, por sua vez, os despachados:

```
SELECT id FROM movimentacao WHERE movimento = 'despachado'
```

Quando fazemos

```
l LEFT JOIN r WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

estamos filtrando os casos sem correspondência do lado direito, ou seja, a condição que você pediu na pergunta.

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5111d/1)**.

Para entender melhor os tipos de `JOIN`:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

Comment: Note que esta solução é tecnicamente similar ao que o Roberto já havia postado antes (que já recebeu meu +1, inclusive), eu só fiz em uma ordem um pouco diferente para ajudar no entendimento.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode selecionar todos os produtos embalados e fazer um `LEFT JOIN` com a mesma tabela, só que dessa vez procurando a linha com o mesmo `Produto` e com a movimentação `despachado`. No `WHERE` filtre para que retorne somente as linhas que não encontraram nada no `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.Produto
FROM sua_tabela a
LEFT JOIN sua_tabela b
    ON a.Produto = b.Produto AND b.Movimentacao = 'despachado'
WHERE a.Movimentacao = 'embalado' AND b.Produto IS NULL
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b0ff/2).